# SUMIF not working

Tags: google-sheets

I have values in column L and I'd like to SUM what is in column B IF the value in L is greater than 1600

Here is my formula:

`=SUMIF(L2:L,">1600",B2:B)`

I'm getting a result of 0 in the cell currently (expecting some numbers as there are values in L larger than 1600)

Comment: Hi, yes it could be, I'm using this formula in L to get the number out of a text cell that begins with numbers: `=LEFT(A2,FIND("x",A2)-1)`

Comment: Ok thanks, was just finding the VALUE function after your comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks as though, as with Excel, the string functions (LEFT, MID, RIGHT) return strings regardless of whether these look like numbers. So a solution is to force conversion with [=VALUE](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3094220) hence:

```
=VALUE(LEFT(A2,FIND("x",A2)-1))
```

in ColumnL should provide the input required for the existing =SUMIF formula to function as intended.